# Jersey2.13: MessageBodyReader not found for StreamingOutput

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I'm returning a StreamingOutput inside a Response object:

```
@GET
@Path("/downloadFile/{filename}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response downloadFile(@PathParam("filename") String fileName) {

    LOG.debug("called: downloadFile({})", fileName);

    final File f = new File("/tmp/" + fileName);

    try {
        if (f.exists()) {
            StreamingOutput so = new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException,
                        WebApplicationException {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        LOG.debug("streaming file contents @{}", bytesRead);
                        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    fis.close();
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                }
            };

            return Response.ok(so, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
        } else {
            return createNegativeXmlResponse("file not found or not readable: '"
                    + f.getPath() + "'");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return handle(e);
    }
}
```

Client side (Junit test case):

```
@Test
public void testDownloadFile() throws Exception {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget target = client.target(BASE_URI).path("/downloadFile/b.txt");
    Response r = target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).get();

    System.out.println(r.getStatus());

    Object o = r.readEntity(StreamingOutput.class);
    StreamingOutput so = (StreamingOutput) o;
}
```

The server runs in a tomcat7 instance. What I get on the client side when r.readEntity is executed is this:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain, type=interface javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput, genericType=interface javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput.
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:230)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:154)
...
```

How can I get the StreamingOutput object from the Response object on the client side ?

Answer (score 2):

`StreamingOutput` is a helper class to allow us to write directly to the response output stream, but is not meant to be recreated from the response, so there is no reader to convert the byte stream to a `StreamingOutput`. We could simple get an `InputStream` from the response though.

```
Response response = target.request().get();
InputStream is = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
```

Full example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestStreamingOutput extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("/streaming")
    public static class StreamingResource {

        @GET
        public StreamingOutput getImage() throws Exception {
            final InputStream is 
                    = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSnus.gif").openStream();
            return new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream out)
                        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    is.close();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(StreamingResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Response response = target("streaming").request().get();
        InputStream is = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(is));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(icon));
    }
}
```

Only Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Result:

[image]